# indexed list with static cells

Tags: uitableview, static, indexing, cells

Newbie here,

A couple of questions:

1. I must use a static cell type in order to use an indexed list, correct?

   I ask this because I've created an app with dynamic prototype cells and have realized 
   that I want to use an Index List for navigation. It's a dictionary app.
2. If I must a static cell type, how do I add a search bar?

   I want users to be able to search at the top as well as use the Indexed List. Like 
   Contacts.
3. How do I go about converting my code for each tab (there are 5 of them) to work with 
   static cells instead of dynamic prototype cells?

I' feeling fairly lost right now. Would it be better to start from scratch?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use dynamic, but better will be when you show some code from your app.

You can ceck this video for some experience with static, dynamic and custom cells:
http://youtu.be/fnzkcV_XUw8

Sorry for write this as answer but i cant adding comments for now.